# How to convert NSInlineData to string?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

In my application I have implemented google map street view so I parse Street view api using AFNetworking , but the response object was NSInline Data and unable to convert to string please help me to get the object..

The coding part was,

```
let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json", "image/jpeg"]) as Set<NSObject> as Set<NSObject>! as! Set<String>?
    let url:NSString = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x300&location=29.812113,-95.441671&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=AIzaSyBzUYqzUts1fwZMG3EPGZyi3_aMr632HGJBH" as NSString)
    print(url)
    manager.get(url as String, parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: {
        (operation, responseObject) in
        let locStr:String = responseObject as! String . -->here error shows like could not cast value type nsinlinedata to string.
        print("locStr is:",locStr)
    }, failure: {
        (operation, error) in
        print(error)
    })
```

Comment: You should post more than one line of code. How can you expect to get help by not showing what you are working on.

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 3 & 4 I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response object is of Data type, try:

```
if let data = responseObject  as? Data { 
    let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) 
}
```

Comment: If Condition checks true, but the dataStr was shows nil..?

Comment: This is how to convert Data (AKA NSData) into a string. @B.SaravanaKumar, If you tried this and it isn't working, then you need to debug your code.